# ExecStartPre= with Restart=always with systemD

Tags: systemd, services

I've a systemd service with  `Restart=always`, `ExecStartPre=/bin/...` and `ExecStart=`

All of the Process exit after about 1 second with exit code 0.

Which process is started again? ExecStartPre and ExecStart or only ExecStart?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/